# Making the whole header section of accordion clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am using accordion like this and I have that glyphicon arrows I can click on to expand/collapse it.  : http://www.bootply.com/1fDNAjGFrJ

```js
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function() {
  $(this).children(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-up glyphicon-chevron-down");
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordionMessagesSetup">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionMessagesSetup" href="#collapseMessagesSetup">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                        Message Setup
                    </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseMessagesSetup" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div>
          Actual Content goes here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The clickable area currently is just that icon. How can expand it to make the whole `panel-title` section **clickable** ?

Comment: Produce a working fiddle link.

Comment: @NathanL  added http://www.bootply.com/1fDNAjGFrJ

Comment: Answer added as below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the anchor for panel title to have a `block` display.

For instance,

```
.panel-title a {
    display: block;
}
```

[WORKING LINK](http://www.bootply.com/RzoHvRh78E)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple css case, let `a` be a `block` and use `padding` to fill title:

```
.accordion-toggle {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.panel-heading {
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer - removing padding from the parent and adding it to the anchor element is a good option - the whole entire heading then becomes clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your css

```
.accordion-toggle{
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: just in case, you would not want to override the functionality at some point while adding more css

Comment: `!important` simply overrides what you have mentioned. So better it is avoided to force it unnecessarily.